# Removing the rows from dataframe till the actual column names are found

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading tabular data from the email in the pandas dataframe.
There is no guarantee that column names will contain in the first row.Sometimes data is in the following format.The actual column names are [ID,Name and Year]

```
dummy1           dummy2     dummy3
test_column1 test_column2 test_column3
ID     Name        Year
1      John        Sophomore
2      Lisa        Junior
3      Ed          Senior
```

Sometimes the column names come in the first row as expected.

```
ID     Name        Year
1      John        Sophomore
2      Lisa        Junior
3      Ed          Senior
```

Once I read the HTML table from the email,how I remove the initial rows that don't contain the column names?So in the first case I would need to remove first 2 rows in the dataframe(including column row) and in the second case,i wouldn't have to remove anything.

Also,the column names can be in any sequence.
basically,I want to do in following

```
1.check whether once of the column names contains in one of the rows in dataframe
2.Remove the rows above
if "ID" in row:
    remove the above rows
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: what's the format of the original data? Is it HTML? plain text?

Comment: HTML..I am reading the tables where i find the <table> tag.I am reading the tables in the list, and the processing it.My code structure looks like the following
for df in list_df:
     #check which row contains column names in the df
     #remove the rows above that
     #do other processing

Comment: pandas read_html accepts a header parameter that allows you to skip rows. it's better to identify the number of rows first, and read the HTML later. Can you provide sample data - I can try to write a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first get `index` of valid columns and then filter and set accordingly.

```
df = pd.read_csv("d.csv",sep='\s+', header=None)
```

```
col_index = df.index[(df == ["ID","Name","Year"]).all(1)].item()    # get columns index

df.columns = df.iloc[col_index].to_numpy()   # set valid columns
df = df.iloc[col_index + 1 :]                # filter data
df
  ID  Name       Year
3  1  John  Sophomore
4  2  Lisa     Junior
5  3    Ed     Senior
```

or

If you want to se `ID` as index

```
df = df.iloc[col_index + 1 :].set_index('ID')
df
    Name       Year
ID
1   John  Sophomore
2   Lisa     Junior
3     Ed     Senior
```

Comment: thanks but it's giving me following error
col_index = df.index[(df == ["ID","Name","Year"]).all(1)].item()    # get columns index
ValueError: Invalid broadcasting comparison [ID","Name","Year"] with block values

Comment: Then i guess may be you are using old version pandas. i tried in pandas 1.x it's working. Anyway which version are you using?

Comment: i am using 0.25.3

Comment: well it's not version issue. I tried in `0.25.3` it's working there also.

Comment: Thanks..Just one more query..the number of columns in the dataframe can be variable,but ["ID","Name","Year"] will always be there..I want to look for any of these 3 columns..in that case how can I modify the above code? I thried this ```df.index[(df == ["ID","Name","Year"]).any(1)].item()``` but it's wrong..I also tried ```df.index[("ID" in df)].item()```..but it's wrong

Comment: @TLanni sorry did not get you what do you mean by "the number of columns in the dataframe can be variable"

Answer (score 0):

Ugly but effective quick try:

```
id_name = df.columns[0]
df_clean = df[(df[id_name] == 'ID') | (df[id_name].dtype == 'int64')]
```